# Is the date of this question a bug?

Tags: support, answers

The following question has received 14 upvotes, the answer to it even 35 upvotes, and is allegedly only 1 day old. The amount of upvotes is just astronomical for our site.

[image]

I have never seen this question show up in the Health feed. The user of one comment has not been active on the site for 4 months now.

Is the date of question and answer a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question was migrated here from Chemistry.SE, where it was on the Hot Network Questions list.

Comment: Yup, this is correct. (I asked the question in question.)

Comment: Ah, that's why. Thanks for the clarification @halcyon, Mark